# WPF MVVM Override X button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there any way to override X (red cross) button of the application in MVVM way?

I want that button to hide window in tray (i have already configured tray icon), but don't know how to  hide window in a proper way.

Comment: You may customize your window using [`WindowChrome`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netcore-3.1) and bind any command to close button without breaking any MVVM rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `OnClosing()` method.

This is my `MainWindow` code, you can place this wherever your main window is.

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

The `e.Cancel = true` is pertinent here, as setting the Cancel to true cancels the close request so the application is not actually closed.

### Edit

I just noticed that your post says ***in MVVM way***, by which I assume you mean writing the code in your `View Model`? If that is the case, `MVVM` patter does not dictate that you write zero-code in your code-behind. The idea of `MVVM` is to decouple `View`, `Model`, and `ViewModel`, but you are still permitted to have code like this when necessary. It doesn't break any `MVVM` rules, so to speak.

Comment: But it breaks mvvm pattern, doesn't it?

EDIT
Ok, i see, thx